# White spaces in database's field

Tags: database, whitespace, trim, removing-whitespace

I have field called `Name` in my database. Its type is `nvarchar(20)`. When I add data to database and fill this field with some "**Foo data**" it turns out that value from this database's field is not equal to "**Foo data**" because in database there is "**Foo data**            " (with 8 spaces). It really makes me furious because I have to use `String.Trim()` after fetching data from DB.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Your description sounds more like you are actually using the `NCHAR` data type. Can you show us the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Right. It's `nchar` instead of `varchar`. My mistake. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you will likely need a "trim"; in this case, my guess is that the input data may have the blank spaces after it.  (Without knowing where the input comes from, though, it's hard to say).  Thus, you'd need to trim out the whitespace before INSERTing the data.

You can run a query to sanitize the existing data; the exact method may depend on the specific database you are using.

Beyond that, you may just have to trim it as you retrieve it.

Comment: Inserting is fine. Those were unit tests which discovered problem. Unfortunately I made a mistake during creating DB. This field was type of `nchar`.